# Git how do i rebase out certain commits?

Tags: git, rebase, git-pull, git-fetch

Here is my tree:

```
    C (featureB)
    |
    |
A - H (master)
|
|
|- H - D (featureA)
```

I would like to make it become

```
    C - D (featureB)
    |
    |
A - H (master)
|
|
|- H - D (featureA)
```

How do I do this in git?

Comment: That's not a "rebase out", that's more of a "rebase in". :-)  Or more specifically a cherry-pick, as @Cupcake notes.

Answer (score 1):

You can `cherry-pick` D onto `featureB`:

```
$ git checkout featureB
$ git cherry-pick D
```